# Cannot specify path variable on a Flow / Send Request

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I was playing with Postman Flows, and I was trying to learn by using the Trello API. All requests work on their own if executed manually. I've also debugged values using the terminal to understand where the problem lies. Before that, here's a summary of what I'm doing.

1. Get all boards for a given trello workspace
2. For each board, delete that board.

The complete flow looks like this:

[image]

I've checked that on the last block `Send Request`, the looped value of `/variable/id` outputs the proper board id. I've done this by checking with a terminal block and a string block. I started suspecting that this is caused by a failure of Postman to understand that the variable I'm trying to use is a path variable and not a query parameter. As such I tried to pass a static value to the `Send Request` and it 404'ed as well (tech aside: in theory for `n` ids it should give me one 200 and `n-1` 404s since the variable is static and the board would not be able to be deleted multiple times).

My suspicion comes from the fact that when configuring the block for this request:

[image]

You do not get prompted to add the `board` variable. I've tried to type it in anyway, and even use combinations like `:board`, with no avail. In fact like I said above, if I use these variables with static values, it still 404s.

[image]

> ignore the parsing message on the right hand side...

As you can see, `board` doesn't show up. Did I end up hitting a bug, or is this user error? One thing I do not know how to do, but would help clarify that the issue is that a null value is being passed on to the `DELETE` would be to output the request itself. On a terminal block I can only see the response.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

After checking the Postman console on the app, I've noticed that in fact the path variable being used is whatever is set on the collection request. It's like it takes the URL as a static field and disregards the path variables. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can see all information of request-response in `Console` tab as usual.

Comment: one of the ways I could think of is to add the path param (eg: board) as a variable in the environment. that way you could set the variable in the flow before sending the request.

Answer (score 2):

Path variables won't be available in your `Send Request`. Instead, define your path variable with an environment/collection/global variable (i.e. `{{board}}`) in the value of the path variable. Then it will show up the relevant block of your flow.

[image]